# Is it proper to use ViewModel for the ListView and the <T> in the ListView?

Tags: android, listview, kotlin, viewmodel

### Preamble

In trying to get my head around the Kotlin classes to implement Android's ViewModel (and MVVM pattern) as used with Fragments and Activities, it is not clear to me of the trade-offs among the various complex classes especially how they have inherited implicit operations and visible methods (e.g., from the observer objects, managed scope, etc.) versus the old O-O approach of passing list-items and lists between activities in an intent as a bundle or reference, etc.

To illustrate my learning dilemma, I am implementing a crunchy cookie and and a jar to contain the cookies.  The cookies can be created, consumed and viewed inside the cookie jar.

Android code tends to be vague on details of classes and the tutorials use deprecated versions, so it is difficult to follow best-practices with the latest version of the Android Architecture Component libraries.

### Pseudo Kotlin code:

```
data class CrunchieCookie : {
   var flavor: String?
   var calories: String?
   var photo: ImageView?

}

class CrunchieCookieViewModel : ViewModel() {
   val _crunchieCookie: CrunchieCookie?
   val crunchieCookie: CrunchieCookie = _crunchieCookie
}

class CookieJarListViewModel: ViewModel() {
    val _cookieJar: MutableLiveData<CrunchieCookie>?
    val cookieJar: LiveData<CrunchieCookie> = _cookieJar
}
```

### Purpose

- I am expecting to create, update and destroy crunchie-cookies
- I am expecting to put crunchie-cookies in a cookie-jar (and take them out)
- I am expecting to list all the crunchie-cookies in the cookie-jar in a scrolling ListView
- I am expecting to click on a crunchie-cooking in the cookie-jar to open an detail view of the cookie
- Finally, storing the cookie-jar in a remote DB, so planning for the local/remote data-source in the future

So, to my way of thinking, the cookie viewmodel will be used in CRUD operations and reused in the detail view from the list model.

Comment: Your ViewModel should have a `LiveData<List<CrunchyCookie>>`. The Fragment containing the ListView should observe the LiveData for changes and pass the List along to the ListView when the LiveData value changes. If you're actually just modifying the contents of a MutableList, then you need to set the value of the MutableLiveData to that same list to inform it that there's a change it needs to notify observers about.

Answer (score 0):

MAKING @Tenfour04 's COMMENT AN ANSWER.

Your ViewModel should have a LiveData<List>. The Fragment containing the ListView should observe the LiveData for changes and pass the List along to the ListView when the LiveData value changes. If you're actually just modifying the contents of a MutableList, then you need to set the value of the MutableLiveData to that same list to inform it that there's a change it needs to notify observers about. – Tenfour04 Sep 9 at 0:02